# WPF Style Trigger to update nested child elements style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a button with an icon and I'm trying to style a button so when it is disabled the icon color is grayed out too. I tired several different ways using style triggers but I can't manage to get it working. I'm quite new to WPF styling so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Button code:

```
<Button x:Name="btnNewProperty" Click="btnNewProperty_Click" Style="{StaticResource iconButton}" Width="145">
    <StackPanel>
        <Viewbox>
            <Path Data="M17,13H13V17H11V13H7V11H11V7H13V11H17M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" />
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock>New Property</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Style I am using:

```
<Application.Resources>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IconColor" Color="#FF444444" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledIconColor" Color="#FF999999" />

<Style x:Key="iconButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Path">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Value="{StaticResource DisabledIconColor}" Property="Fill" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Viewbox}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-4,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IconColor}" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,-2,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>            
</Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into VS 2013 and noticed within your Style the Setter for Template has TargetType of Path. This is not allowed and the XAML editor shows the error.  Your Control Template for the button is not setup correctly.  Here is a link to a nice example of custom buttons that allows you to get the benefits of the button template behaviors:  http://markheath.net/post/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in

Answer (score 0):

Try this style with your button

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF444444" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <StackPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Viewbox>
                                <Path Data="M17,13H13V17H11V13H7V11H11V7H13V11H17M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            </Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock>New Property</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF999999"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score -1):

please within the button style try with this

```
<Button>
  <Image Source="something.png">
    <Image.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Image.Style>
  </Image>
</Button>
```